# CarrierWave - undefined method `image_url'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

so I have yet another unique problem...

I checked this [TOPIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598899/rails-carrierwave-nomethoderror-undefined-method-image-url-for-nilnilclas) and it didnt work... I am out of ideas at this stage...

So I am adding post with upload for image then I am trying to display it along with the content.

[image: Screenshot with Error]

[image: Upload Screenshot]

I really dont understand why this code does not work... Did I forgot something?

**show.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="content-move">
      <div class="row">
        <aside class="col-md-4">
          <section class="user_info">
            <h1>
              <%= gravatar_for @user %>
              <%= @user.name %>
            </h1>
          </section>
        </aside>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
            <h3>User Posts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
            <div>
              <%= image_tag @microposts.image_url.to_s if @microposts.image_url.present? %>
            </div>
            <ol class="microposts">
              <%= render @microposts %>
            </ol>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**_micropost_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(Micropost.new) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new micropost..." %>
      </div>
      <div>
        <%= f.file_field :image %>
      </div>
      <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

**micropost.rb**

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user    # Association with User
      has_many :comments

      mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

      validates :user_id, presence: true
      validates :posttitle, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
      validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 500 }
      validates :posttitle, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }

      default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
<%= image_tag @microposts.image_url.to_s if @microposts.image_url.present? %>
```

`@microposts` is a collection of records, not a single micropost record. You can either display all the images:

```
<% @microposts.each do |mp| %>
  <%= image_tag mp.image_url.to_s if @mp.image_url.present? %>
<% end %>
```

or display image of the first micropost:

```
<%= image_tag @microposts.first.image_url.to_s if @microposts.first.image_url.present? %>
```

However it seems that is something that should be moved inside your `_micropost.html.erb` partial (`render @microposts`), where you can display an image next to the post it belongs to.

Comment: I am trying to display posts with images beside them. Just like you said in the last sentence. How would I use render @microposts in my code?

Comment: @Fresz - You already have it in the code. This line will loop over your collection, rendering `microposts/_micropost` template for each item. So if you want to add an image to every post, you need to do it in that partial.

Comment: Ok, It makes sense when I read it - but when I go back to the code ... no idea how to fix this. Should I put image_tag into render ?

Comment: I got it now - works but its not displaying image - I am guessing there is problem with upload part. Thanks a lot